# Could not find or load main class install4j.Installer?

Tags: java, debian, install4j, studio3t

Hi I'm trying to install studio 3T
and when I execute the .sh file I get
*Unpacking JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
Error: Could not find or load main class install4j.Installer1269427202
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: install4j.Installer1269427202*

i am on debian and i have java installed and this is the java version
*openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)*

Thank you for your help

Comment: The error message suggests that your installer file is incomplete. You need to contact whoever created the .sh file.

Comment: I got the sh file after unpacking the tar file from the studio 3t website following what's here : https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/how-to-install-studio-3t-on-linux/

Comment: Fine. This means you need to contact the 3T team and tell them their installer file is incomplete and that they need to create a new installer.

Comment: Just to be sure: you did not manually modify the .sh file, did you?

Comment: This would happen if the `.install4j` directory was missing the installer package.

Comment: I did not modify the sh file
I contacted 3tstudio, thanks for your suggestion.

I actually tried to install install4j but I get this error
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'int sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.init()'